# DropDownlist preselect multiple items

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to preselect (from my controller) multiple options in a  list. I've tried almost everything, but I am not able to get the items selected.

What's wrong with this?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.UserIds, Model.Users, new { @class = "form-control input-sm chosen", multiple = "multiple"})
```

I've also tried @Html.DropdownList() - without success.

Everything seems to be fine in my model. The selectlist has a selected item and the item's selected property is true, but I only get unselected options.

[image: SelectedValue]
[image: SelectedItem]
[image: Unselected options]

Comment: Resolved: Html.ListBox or Html.ListBoxFor instead of @Html.DropDownList does it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use @Html.ListBox or @Html.ListBoxFor instead of @Html.DropDownList

Comment: Wow. Saved my night! Thanks a lot! Could you please explain why it works with Html.ListBoxFor and doesn't work with Html.DropDownFor ?

Comment: thanks saved me much! i would really appreciate to know why it only works with Html.ListBoxFor.